# Drupal civicrm Contribution Form code into Drupal page content?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, contribution-page

Is it possible embed drupal civicrm Contribution Form code into page content?

Can any one please help me I was trying this for last 3 days, I can't find the solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This looks like a good question.  You could make it better by editing it to include the version of CiviCRM and Drupal you are using.  Also please make it clear if you want the contribution page to appear within the CiviCRM website or in an external website.  If you could say a bit more about what you have tried so far that would also be helpful.

Comment: It would also help if you could explain the rationale for doing it this way. so that rather than someone telling how to do this, someone might tell you how to avoid doing this and doing it some entirely different way. what is the outcome you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install the [Webform-CiviCRM](https://drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module, and this allows you to embed contribution fields in a webform (which is a drupal content type).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, not in generic page content, unless you use an iframe.

Coleman's solution above relies on a lot of complex code (that he wrote ...) to do the embedding/integration for you, and is the best solution if you have Drupal and want to use a Drupal-native form for the contribution page. The other option is to use Drupal commerce and rely on more complex and less reliable integration.

A donation form is not as simple as a regular form, it relies on a lot of server work and magic (for a start, for security, but also for input error handling for example), so simply creating a form that posts to a CiviCRM url won't work.